# adding sticky notes in an existing pdf using java itext or pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to add sticky notes to an existing pdf. please help with any suggestion with itext or pdfbox.

I have tried using pdfbox but couldn't find any solution.
Please help...

Here is the sample pdf of what type of sticky notes I want: http://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf

Comment: Did you try the AddAnnotations.java example from the PDFBox source code download?

Comment: yes, Annotations are not useful for my use case as I want to create sticky notes so every application can open them...

Comment: Can you show an example of a document with sticky notes and applications that can open those sticky notes and access them?

Comment: please check the URL I have attached in my question: http://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

> According to the PDF specification, 'a text annotation represents a
>   “sticky note” attached to a point in the PDF document.' Thus, neither
>   the class `PDAnnotationTextMarkup` nor the subtype `SUB_TYPE_POLYGON`
>   appears to match your requirements. Instead, you should use the
>   `PDAnnotationText` class. As an aside, `PDAnnotationTextMarkup` is
>   documented (JavaDocs) to be the abstract class that represents a text
>   markup annotation. While it is not actually declared abstract, that
>   characterization should make clear that it probably does not work
>   without further ado.

so I used the below code and it worked like magic for me

```
PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
position.setUpperRightX(textPosition.getX());
position.setUpperRightY(ph - textPosition.getY());

position.setLowerLeftX(textPosition.getX()-4);
position.setLowerLeftY(ph - textPosition.getY());
PDGamma colourBlue = new PDGamma();
colourBlue.setB(1);

PDAnnotationText text = new PDAnnotationText();
text.setContents(commentNameWithComments.get(word));
text.setRectangle(position);
text.setOpen(true);
text.setConstantOpacity(50f);

assert annotations != null;
annotations.add(text);
page1.setAnnotations(annotations);
replaceText(word);
```

it might be useful for future devs :-)

Comment: Looks like you were in touch with someone of the Apache PDFBox project? Would be nice if you gave credit to the person who answered your question.

Comment: sure this was suggested by @mkl

Comment: Aha. On some mailing list probably, or on another SO question. @mkl is one of the very few people (also here on Stack Overflow) who has an excellent understanding of the PDF standard *and* has experience with multiple PDF SDKs.